# No query results for model [App\Products] Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

In laravel5 i got following message(error)

```
No query results for model [App\Products].
```

I have a table "`products`" which has a column "`category_id`" that a `category Id` of each category items. I want to show the  items according to `category Id`

My controller is like this

```
 public function category()
{
 $recordsByCategories=\DB::table('products')
            ->select('categories','category_id', \DB::raw('count(*) as totalProducts'))
            ->groupBy('categories')
            ->get();
 return view('dashboard.show',compact('recordsByCategories'));
 }

**//I have received error in below function**

 public function searchCategoryByTag($id)
        {

         $category_id = Products::findOrFail($id);
         $records=\DB::table('products')->Where('category_id','$category_id');
          dd($records);

        }
```

My routes is like this

```
 Route::get('categorys/{id}' ,array(
    'as'=>'category',
    'uses'=>'GoodsController@searchCategoryByTag'));
```

My view is like this

```
@foreach($recordsByCategories as $recordsByCategory)

    <a href="{{URL::route('category',$recordsByCategory->category_id)}}
    " id="search">{{$recordsByCategory->categories}}</a>:{{$recordsByCategory->totalProducts}} 

    @endforeach
```

Comment: Try updating `$records=\DB::table('products')->Where('category_id','$category_id');` to `$records=\DB::table('products')->where('category_id',$category_id->category_id)->get();`

Comment: what is $product in  $product->category_id

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING)

Comment: public function searchCategoryByTag($id)
    {
     $category_id = Products::findOrFail($id);
$records=\DB::table('products')->where('category_id',$category_id->category_id)‌​->get();
     dd($records);

       
    }

Comment: no unexpected "" in code i think

Comment: try `dd($category_id)` in searchCategoryByTag to see if you are getting a product.

Comment: No query results for model [App\Products].

Comment: i  my routes is alright?

Comment: Sounds like there isn't a product matching the id you are trying to find.

Comment: there is "category_id" column in "products" table which i want to fetch

Comment: `Products::findOrFail($id)` isn't receiving a valid id. It's trying to search the `id` column on Products table for a matching id  to value of $id.

Comment: If $id equals category id, do only `$records = Products::where('category_id', $id)->get();` in searchCategoryByTag.

Comment: great, I've added an answer to accept.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have mistaken the `'$category_id'`, remove that single quotes.

```
public function searchCategoryByTag($id)
{
    $category_id = Products::findOrFail($id);
    $records=\DB::table('products')->Where('category_id', $category_id);
}
```

Answer (score 21):

Check your API routes. Make sure nothing is competing with that endpoint that would cause a 404 error on the request for `/products`. This happens to me often.

Answer (score 3):

The `findOrFail` method will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown. You can read more about on this section of [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#not-found-exceptions).

`Product::findOrFail($id);` This code is not getting the product, so it fails. Consider using `find` or `first`, `get` will return an array.

And you need to remove single quotes from `$records=\DB::table('products')->Where('category_id','$category_id');`, so it will became `$records=\DB::table('products')->Where('category_id',$category_id);`.

Answer (score 0):

If $id equals category id, do only `$records = Products::where('category_id', $id)->get();` in searchCategoryByTag.

Answer (score 0):

**You should change form **

```
 $category_id = Products::findOrFail($id);
 $records=\DB::table('products')->Where('category_id','$category_id')->get();
```

**change to this**
 `$records = Products::where('category_id', $id)->get();`

```
`$categroy_id `
```

**is get object form your products table instance of **`$category_id` to `$category_id->id`

Answer (score -2):

Try adding this member to your Product model class;

```
protected $table = 'products';
```