# No query results for model [App\Models\Customer] backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I am using laravel backpack package and while edit and delete or preview operation I am getting the below error.

`No query results for model [App\Models\Customer] record id`

I have included the model. What am I am missing?

And one more thing the record id which is showing in the error it is not present in the table, But the backpack list interface is showing. why?
And this table is a master. Any CRUD operation will happen only for its own tbl only not affecting any other tbl.
Below is controller

```
 <?PHP
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
   use App\Models\Customer;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
   use App\Http\Requests\CustomerRequest;
   use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;
   use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;
   use Carbon\Carbon;

   class CustomerCrudController extends CrudController
  {
   use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ListOperation;
   use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\CreateOperation 
   {store as traitstore;}
   use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\UpdateOperation 
   {update as traitupdate;}
   use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation 
   {destroy as traitDestroy;}
   use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;


public function setup()
{
    //$this->crud->enableExportButtons();
    $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Customer');
    $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/customer');
    $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('customer', 'customers');     
}

protected function setupListOperation()
{
    // TODO: remove setFromDb() and manually define Columns, maybe Filters
    //$this->crud->setFromDb();
   
    $this->crud->setColumns([
        [
            'name'  => 'company_name',
            'label' => 'Company',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ],
        [
            'name'  => 'company_address1',
            'label' => 'Primary Add',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ],
        [
            'name'  => 'primary_contact',
            'label' => 'Primary Cont',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ],
        [
            'name'  => 'company_city',
            'label' => 'city',
            'type'  => 'text',
        ]
    ]);
   

    }
}
```

Model is

```
<?PHP 
   
namespace App\Models;
use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'customers';
    protected $primaryKey = "cust_id";

    protected $fillable = [
        'company_name',
        'company_address1',
        'company_address2',
        'company_city',
        'company_zip',
        'company_country',
        'company_state',
        'company_vat',
        'company_id',
        'primary_contact',
        'technical_contact',
        'financial_contact',
        'cust_def_time_zone',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'deleted_at' ];
}
```

Comment: Show your code and model file too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No query results for model \[App\Products\] Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585912/no-query-results-for-model-app-products-laravel)

Comment: *NO*. DB table's id is different and the records fetched by laravel-backpack id is different. I don't know this is happening.

Comment: I have found a solution. In the laravel-backpack table "id" field is considered to be primary. But i don't want to use the "id" field as the primary key any solution for that?

Comment: Hmm, that shouldnt be the case. Backpack doesnt presupose what your primary key should be, it uses `$entity->getKey()` to get the value which is provided by laravel and should always take into account the `$primaryKey` attribute for the model. Can you show the migration that created this table, or the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE customers;`?

Comment: @WesleySmith, In my tbl "id", is the unique key which is auto-increment, but not primary. I am using another field as a primary key which is UUID. But when i am assigning xyz_id as $primaryKey, the backpack is taking only the first letter of that UUID. When i run SHOW CREATE TABLE customers; It show only id column with not null. No other data is shown for customer tbl.

Comment: If your model's primary key is a uuid string, please add this to your model `protected $keyType = 'string';`

Comment: Thank you. @WesleySmith, It is working now

Comment: Awesome, Yvw, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

edit **setupShowOperation** function in **CustomerCrudController**
add this

```
Customer::withTrashed()->find(\request()->id);
```